# Passbook save pem file in AWS

Tags: ruby, security, certificate, aws-sdk, passbook

I would like to create a passbook sign at my ruby server hosted on AWS. what is the best way to save .pem files or .p12 file in AWS ? and retrieve them to sign the passbook.
I'm using passbook gem in  https://github.com/frozon/passbook but note at the example he use files from local path

```
   Passbook.configure do |passbook|
      passbook.wwdc_cert = Rails.root.join('wwdc_cert.pem')
      passbook.p12_key = Rails.root.join('key.pem')
      passbook.p12_certificate = Rails.root.join('certificate.pem')
      passbook.p12_password = 'cert password'
   end
```

In my case I want to read them from AWS

Answer (score 0):

Just use the url of your files hosted on amazon. Like

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>
```